# Where should I add a Rack module (a class to be exact) I wrote? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I have written a simple Rack module that I put in a file I named `rack_gist.rb`. Somewhere in my `config.ru` file, I use `use Rack::Gist` to call that module. I know the module works, and I know `use Rack::Gist` is put in the right place, because when I put the code present in `rack_gist.rb` at the top of my `config.ru` file, everything works perfectly.

I'm using Rails 3.2.2. I want to separate the code of the module in a `rack_gist.rb` file, so I added the line `config.middleware.use Rack::Gist` in my `config/application.rb` file. My question is: **where should I now put the `rack_gist.rb` file? Should I require anything anywhere?**

Just to be clearer, here's my module

```
   module Rack
      class Gist
        def initialize(app)
          @app = app
        end
        def call(env)
          status, @headers, response = @app.call(env)
          if html?
            #do something I don't want to bother you with
          end
          [status, @headers, response]
        end
        private
        def html?
          @headers["Content-Type"].include? "text/html"
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

imho, this is what you can do.
Place your code into lib directory `lib/rack_gist.rb`

Add lib initilizer to initializers

```
#config/initializers/lib_loader.rb
Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root.to_s,'lib','*.rb'))].each {|f| require f}
```

And then your module should be available to add it to config.

Comment: For the record, I used lib/modules/ as my folder for this. It just felt wrong having files at the same level as 'assets' and 'tasks'. Also, if there were multiple files for your rack_gist module, you should store them in lib/modules/rack_gist/ and use lib/modules/rack_gist.rb to require them in.